# Spark 1.2 SQL code does not work with Spark 1.3 SQL code

Tags: sbt, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have used so far this build.sbt in the local package directory

```
name := "spark27_02"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

sbtVersion := "0.13.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.2.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.5.0"
```

i wanted to try out the 1.3.0 version that just came out, so i used the 1.3.0 versions of all the packages. Spark compiles, but SparkSQL does not, so I checked MavenCentral that suggests to use

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.3.0"
```

but still not working.
I do sbt update from the sbt shell.
Btw using Scala 2.10.4

What silly thing am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT
referring to the example on the spark webpage with this build.sbt

```
name := "Marzia2"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

sbtVersion := "0.13.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.3.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.3.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.3.0"
```

doing

```
sbt package
```

i get

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/cloudera/IdeaProjects/Marzia2/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/cloudera/IdeaProjects/Marzia2/src/main/scala/prova_sql.scala:35: value createSchemaRDD is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
[error]     import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
[error]            ^
[error] /home/cloudera/IdeaProjects/Marzia2/src/main/scala/prova_sql.scala:38: value registerTempTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[prova_sql.Person]
[error]     people.registerTempTable("people")
[error]            ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

and in case i use the new features like `implicits` in defining the spark context, i still get an error relating to it not being an error of the sparksql context.

There must be some stupid error somewhere.

Comment: @JustinPihony please, see the edits

Answer (score 6):

One part of the problem is that `SchemaRDD` became a `DataFrame`. Realistically, you should use

```
import sqlContext._
```

instead of the specific import as it will future proof you against implicit changes, but if you really want then you can use

```
import sqlContext.implicits
```

BUT, the second part is that 1.3.0 broke compatibility and is now locked in from an API perspective, so you now need to do the following:

- The implicits are not fully blown as 1.2. In order to use them, you now have to do: `rdd.toDF().registerTempTable("xyz")`

Note the `toDF`

Now that the API is locked in, I cannot think of a way to add the more intuitive `implicit` back in. You would end up with conflicting `implicit` definitions for the case of import `sqlContext._` and nested implicits are not supported in scala.

From the [migration guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#migration-guide):

> Additionally, the implicit conversions now only augment RDDs that are
>   composed of Products (i.e., case classes or tuples) with a method
>   toDF, instead of applying automatically.